# NSString format with NSBackgroundColor keeps going after text on top text lines

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring

I have NS String that prints "W ####:\n (on new line) H:####"  and it has background color black with 65% opacity, but this background color keeps going last text on first line and not the second. I would like for background color to stop as well along with text characters. How do i do this? Please explain it if you can as I am super new to coding and still don't understand much.

```
    if (_screenFontEnable){
       [_sfColor set];

        int x=0;
        float y=37;
        float z=10;

        NSString *new=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",((y/z)*_screenFontSize)];
        x =[new intValue];
        NSLog(@"%@" ,new);

        NSString *canvasLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "W %.4i:\n H %.4i",screenSizeWidth,screenSizeHeight];
     [canvasLabel drawAtPoint:NSPointFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%i,%i}",((screenSizeWidth/2)-x), (screenSizeHeight/2)-(_screenFontSize/2)])

               withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:screensize],
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName:_sfColor,
                                NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[[NSColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.65]

                                }];
```

}

[screen shot of what it prints rite now [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwNSZ.png)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use a label subview or draw as 2 separate items?

Comment: well i had hell of a time just getting this to work as i mentioned i am new to this so i did it the only way i know how. if you can suggest another way thats easier i am all for it. my problem was user can change the _screenFontSize and that would change location of text  and i couldn't really come up with formulas to center the text in my rectangle which is also something that changes in size by user via screenSizeWidth and screenSizeHeight

Comment: A label subview and autolayout will deal with multiple lines, font size and screen size